# Should we discourage links to JSFiddle collaboration sessions?

Tags: discussion, jsfiddle

If someone provides a link to JSFiddle, it should ideally be a version of their code that matches what's in the question. If someone posts a link to a collaboration session, it will be a moving target. Also, if you follow the link, you may have to interact with the poster, or deal with it changing out from under you as you're trying to see what they wrote.

I generally find these collaboration sessions more annoying than useful, I wonder of others feel the same way. I think that Stack Overflow should display a warning when someone tries to post a question containing this type of link.

And they should probably be prohibited entirely in answers -- I can't see how that could possibly be useful.

For reference, these links look like:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=XXXXXXX
```

Comment: Not a duplicate, but sort-of-related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276143/has-the-check-for-js-fiddle-links-among-others-changed-recently (mine is a bug report, about allowing collaboration links to be posted without code in the question).

Comment: I'm sure you won't be surprised that the question about tabs was the one that prompted me to post this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[remyabel makes some really good arguments for this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276325/should-we-discourage-links-to-jsfiddle-collaboration-sessions/276345#276345), but the best reason to block them outright is simply that [they break the logic that's supposed to encourage people to include the code in the post itself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276143/has-the-check-for-jsfiddle-links-among-others-changed-recently/283308#283308):

> This design avoids blocking links to the default pages for the various code-hosting services while still enforcing the code restriction on likely links to *hosted code*. But it falls apart completely for these "collaboration" links, which contain the relevant identifiers in the URL fragment.

The combination of a link that can't be relied on to be current AND no easy way to see what the code was when the question was posted is a real deal-breaker. So I've blacklisted these links on Stack Overflow:

[image: Body cannot contain...]

Answer (score 31):

Having an off-site collaborative link is not useful to anybody except the OP. People are free to fork the code in the question and post attempts in the comments before moving *definitive* code into an answer, but having code that fluctuates widely in the question is not useful to anybody. It also shifts responsibility to an off-site link which renders Stack Overflow's collaborative tools useless.

Now we have stack snippets which allow the code to stay on-site *and* benefit from SO's collaborative tools.

Secondly, these kinds of sites suffer from serious link rot. There are many [ideone](http://ideone.com/) links on old questions which no longer work, where the answerer didn't bother to post the code in the answer.

Ben Voigt has pointed out in the [ideone faq](http://ideone.com/faq) this particular gem:

> **How long my codes will be stored on Ideone?**
>
> Forever.

Comment: ideone.com is a particular problem because they persist in not following [their own terms](http://ideone.com/faq).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I find them kind of fun. An opportunity to be all "oh hi!" with other people who happen to be viewing the question. Lots of fun has been had in comments, and I see it as a fun distraction from whatever stressful thing I'm doing at a time.

**I don't see this as a problem.**

But why?

Because *all links are subject to change*. This is the Internet. So, collaboration links are just as valid as "normal" JSFiddle links. Namely, *the question should have the (original) code in it!* If it doesn't, then there's a bigger problem than a collaboration link. See David Thomas' [bug report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276143/has-the-check-for-jsfiddle-links-among-others-changed-recently) for more on that.

Comment: AFAIK, JSFiddle doesn't provide a way to change the code in a link. Whenever you edit the fiddle, it creates a new version with a different URL. And if you want to be all "oh hi", use chat.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that's true, JSFiddle offers permalinks, but nothing on the internet is truly permanent.

Comment: ++ for pointing out that the ***real*** issue is that the code wasn't embedded in the question to begin with.

Answer (score -2):

This is really just the latest instalment in what is essentially an ongoing argument over whether Stack Overflow is an asynchronous collaboration tool or a sort of gamified wiki.

A sane answer is "both" but people aren't reasonable so it evolved into a slow-motion war of persecution of those who want to use it as a self-ranking communication and collaboration tool by those who want to use it as a cross between an encyclopaedia and an honour roll.

The answer to the posed question is "yes" if you're the persecutor and "no" if you're the persecuted.

Comment: In recognition of this, I've blocked these links in *posts only* - they'll still be allowed in comments (or in chat) for those who wish to engage in real-time collaboration.

Comment: @Shog: Nice balance. Sometimes one can really have the cake and eat it too ;-)