# 'Links to jsfiddle.net' restriction does not apply to the https://fiddle.jshell.net/ domain

Tags: bug, asking-questions, editor, jsfiddle

After coming accross [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44695739/select-option-value-on-change) I have noticed that the logic for restricting questions that link to jsFiddle.net without placing any code in the question is missing this domain:

> https://fiddle.jshell.net/

This would appear to be a bug given the behaviour when entering a link using the `http://jsfiddle.net` domain, ie:

[image]

Comment: You'd think this would have been discovered and reported much sooner...

Comment: Shog9 needs to fiddle the [regex](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283308/578411)

Comment: What other sites does this restriction apply to? If only jsFiddle, can we get it expanded to codepen as well?